# including array of string into "where GTID in (arrayname)" clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, vb.net

I have array of strings in `GTIDArr`

Letus say `GTID={"CODE1","CODE2","CODE3"}`

I wanted to fetch records from database with below query having GTID as above.

Hence I made following thing:

```
Dim sqlTransferExcel As String = " select gt.GTID ,gt.TransferDate ,pl.LocationName as FromLocation,Pto.LocationName as ToLocation,gt.TransferedMode ,gt.TransferedDetails ,gt.Remarks ,p.ProductName+case when c.CategoryName IS null then '' else  '-'+c.CategoryName end as PName,gd.QtyTransferred  " _
                                      & " from dbo.GoodTransferDetails gd Left outer join ProductMaster p on gd.ProductID =p.ProductID " _
                                      & " Left Outer join CategoryMaster c on gd.CategoryID =c.CategoryID " _
                                      & " Left Outer join dbo.GoodTransfer gt on gt.GTID=gd.GTID  " _
                                      & " Left Outer join  PescaLocation pl on  gt.FromPescaLocation =pl.PLID " _
                                      & " Left Outer join PescaLocation Pto  on gt.ToPescaLocation =pto.PLID " _
                                      & " where gd.GTID in ( '" & GTIDArr() & "' ) order by p.OrderID  "
```

But its giving me error for last line in where condition as

> Error 101 Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of
>   the indexed

How can i have array of strings in this query??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example use `Join` method from `String`:

```
String.Join(", ", GTIDArr)
```

If you need to quote each element from array, try that:

```
"'" & String.Join("', '", GTIDArr) & "'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo can do it by using LINQ

```
string Command= string.Empty;
 Command= string.Join(",", ArrayListName.Cast<string>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()); // If it is INT Type
 Command= string.Join("','", ArrayListName.Cast<string>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()); // If it is String
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use array directly wit the & in this sql statement to use & in your array so you first you have to convert to string then you have to use .see below code and you find the solution easily:

```
Dim GTIDArr As String() = {"CODE1", "CODE2", "CODE3"}

Dim value As String = String.Join(",", GTIDArr)

Dim sqlTransferExcel As String = " select gt.GTID ,gt.TransferDate ,pl.LocationName as FromLocation,Pto.LocationName as ToLocation,gt.TransferedMode ,gt.TransferedDetails ,gt.Remarks ,p.ProductName+case when c.CategoryName IS null then '' else  '-'+c.CategoryName end as PName,gd.QtyTransferred  " _
  & " from dbo.GoodTransferDetails gd Left outer join ProductMaster p on gd.ProductID =p.ProductID " _
  & " Left Outer join CategoryMaster c on gd.CategoryID =c.CategoryID " _
  & " Left Outer join dbo.GoodTransfer gt on gt.GTID=gd.GTID  " _
  & " Left Outer join  PescaLocation pl on  gt.FromPescaLocation =pl.PLID " _
  & " Left Outer join PescaLocation Pto  on gt.ToPescaLocation =pto.PLID " _
  & " where gd.GTID in ( '" & value & "' ) order by p.OrderID  "
```